# I need show customs labels in my bar chart

Tags: javascript

I have a bar chart with an array for label (days) and another array for datasets (amounts), i need show calculates data above the bars using data label plugin. this data is provided on an api, for this example i create  variables for represents this data. 
XValues ( days)
YValues (Amounts)
porcentaje ( Porcentaje) I need show this porcentage value each 90 days trimester.

[I need Show This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdadl.png)

How to use datalabel charts plugin, formatter and render and display, 
datasets functions

```js
var XValues = [
  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
  21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 
  39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44,45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 
  58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 
  76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 
  94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 
 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 
  125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137,138, 139, 
 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153,154, 
  155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169,  
  170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 
 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 
 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 
 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 
 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 
 245, 246, 247, 248, 249,      250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 
 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 
 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281,282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 
 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 
 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313,314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 
 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 
 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345,346, 347, 348, 
 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360];

var YValues = [  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
 0.0, 50000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1220779.6, 130000.0, 296000.0, 
1162027.14, 0.0, 0.0, 2768482.84, 373769.69, 3266877.14, 954752.3, 0.0, 
2179743.89, 1119815.91, 0.0, 1546573.58, 2295188.35, 5766416.61, 2400059.89, 
1362544.32, 2065125.0, 0.0, 2614227.3, 4312441.03,1567752.45, 396385.85, 
784367.19, 1251550.85, 649401.57, 1960851.15, 2418563.82, 
5763793.94,770000.0, 200000.0, 1000000.0, 489582.34, 8701720.72, 4233160.43, 
0.0, 800000.0, 3275422.23, 0.0, 0.0, 10834000.0, 9480157.63, 5458915.89, 
48660.23,3076394.38, 0.0, 1248800.0, 1300000.0, 3239404.21, 4721667.16, 
6325239.51, 723000.0,     120500.0, 0.0, 2700856.83, 300000.0, 6085455.79, 
12365548.65, 250000.0, 2275793.87,  816111.3, 2312688.39, 1193043.0, 
1684344.47, 650000.0, 2970000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 814123.8,  3000000.0, 1482929.54, 
1597000.0, 2145474.31, 883611.12, 0.0, 1344585.29, 2223230.0,  2906253.0, 
1478849.38, 1100001.0, 0.0, 500347.76, 0.0, 0.0, 1002860.0, 1378000.0, 
2300000.0, 0.0, 672000.0, 12794114.88, 0.0, 1533827.5, 320000.0, 2214936.52, 
0.0, 0.0, 2183429.87, 1200000.0, 2215000.0, 800000.0, 959169.9, 1000000.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 864901.01, 650000.0, 650000.0, 000.0,      300000.0, 239289.19, 
0.0, 200000.0, 2963732.7, 0.0, 20000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1631.66, 300000.0,    0.0, 
250000.0, 250000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 622281.05, 0.0, 20000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0,  758217.94, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2250000.0, 337580.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  150000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 855543.06, 
36700.0, 0.0, 370000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 200000.0,
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 130000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0  ];

var porcentajes = [30, 8, 10, 6, 3];

var barChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("sub"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: XValues,
    datasets: [{
      label: "Cheques",
      data: YValues,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(100,100,200, .4)",
      borderColor: "rgba(100,100,200, 1)",
      borderWidth: 1.5
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(t, d) {
          return d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label
        },
        afterLabel: function(t, d) {
          return [t.xLabel + " Días", "$ " + t.yLabel.toLocaleString('es-AR')];
        },
        title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return;
        },
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{

        barThickness: 3,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 5,

          autoSkip: true,
          maxTicksLimit: 12
        },

        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          fontSize: 8,
          labelString: 'Vencimiento (dias)'
        },

      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          fontSize: 8,
          labelString: 'Importe ($)'
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          callback: function(label, index, labels) {
            if (label == 0) {
              return "   0";
            }
            if (label >= 1 && label <= 9) {
              return "     " + label;
            }
            if (label >= 10 && label <= 99) {
              return "   " + label;
            }
            if (label >= 100 && label <= 999) {
              return " " + label;
            }
            if (label >= 1000 && label <= 9999) {
              return "   " + (label + "").slice(0, 1) + "K";
            }
            if (label >= 10000 && label <= 99999) {
              return " " + (label + "").slice(0, 2) + "K";
            }
            if (label >= 100000 && label <= 999999) {
              return "0." + (label + "").slice(0, 1) + "M";
            }
            if (label >= 1000000 && label <= 9999999) {
              return "   " + (label + "").slice(0, 1) + "M";
            }
            if (label >= 10000000 && label <= 99999999) {
              return " " + (label + "").slice(0, 2) + "M";
            }
            if (label >= 100000000 && label <= 999999999) {
              return (label + "").slice(0, 3) + "M";
            }
            if (label >= 1000000000 && label <= 9999999999) {
              return " " + (label + "").slice(0, 1) + "mM";
            }
            if (label >= 10000000000 && label <= 99999999999) {
              return (label + "").slice(0, 2) + "mM";
            }
          }
        },

      }]
    },

    Plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'end',
        aling: 'end',

      }
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>


<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!--Boostrap Styles-->
<!-- <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/myCustomStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <canvas id="sub" height="100"></canvas>
      <!-- Bar chart-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- <script src="lib/moment/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels/src/chartjs-plugin-labels.js"></script>


  <!-- <script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>     -->
  <!-- <script src="lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   -->

</body>

</html>
```

[Original fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xqp2s567](https://jsfiddle.net/xqp2s567)

Comment: What library are you using? can you create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: i'm using charts js and datalabel plugin this is my fiddle label: https://jsfiddle.net/xqp2s567